# separable points on n-sphere

Tags: metric-spaces, area, spheres

Consider a metric space $(S^n, d)$, where $S^n$ is $n$-dimensional unit sphere and $d(x, y) = \cos ^{-1}(x \cdot y)$. I need to put as much points on the sphere s.t. distance between any two points will be larger than some constant $C$. Is it true that the maximum amount of points can be put on 6-sphere (which has the biggest area)?

Comment: I did not understand the question. The amount of points you can put depends on the constant $C$.

Comment: Also, is there any reason for you to expect that the maximum amount of points will be obtained for $n=6$?

Comment: It is assumed to be fixed, e.g. 0.1. Yes, I guess that it is somehow related to the area of the sphere.

Comment: I see. Also, is there any reason for you to suspect that this number is finite? Intuitively, as $n$ grows this number should grow as there is more "space" to put extra points, right?

Comment: No, I think that there is less space, as sphere's area tends to 0.

Comment: @nmerci I agree with the above posters that this question is not well posed. The maximum number of points depends on $C$ and tends towards infinity as $C \to 0$. Also regarding your last statement I think that surface area is the relevant quantity.

Comment: @basket $C$ is a constant, fixed in advance. I do not look for maximum number of points -- I look for dimension $n$ at which this maximum can be reached. I am almost sure it does not depend on $C$.

Comment: @nmerci - Suppose $C = \frac \pi 2$ and allow the angle to be $\ge C$, not just greater. Then it is obvious that $S^n$ allows at least $2(n+1)$ points, simply by taking the intersections with the coordinate axes in $\Bbb R^{n+1}$. It should also be clear that you can't fit too many more points than that. I.e., for this particular value of $C$, it should be obvious that the number of points placable goes to $\infty$ as $n$ rises. There is no $n$ that provides a maximum.